# face-api.min.js load images from local disk

Tags: face-api

I'm trying to load images from my local disk. Main folder is called "Face Recognition" and images are stored in /labeled_images.

```
function loadLabeledImages() {
  const labels = ['Black Widow', 'Captain America', 'Captain Marvel', 'Hawkeye', 'Jim Rhodes', 'Thor', 'Tony Stark', 'Elon Musk']
  return Promise.all(
    labels.map(async label => {
      const descriptions = []
      for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        //const img = await faceapi.fetchImage(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WebDevSimplified/Face-Recognition-JavaScript/master/labeled_images/${label}/${i}.jpg`) **//THIS IS WHAT WAS ORIGINALLY WRITTEN**
        const img = await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromDisk(path.join(__dirname, '/labeled_images')) **//THIS IS THE CODE I CHANGED**
        const detections = await faceapi.detectSingleFace(img).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptor()
        descriptions.push(detections.descriptor)
      }

      return new faceapi.LabeledFaceDescriptors(label, descriptions)
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In linux we can load images with relative adress:

```
const img = await faceapi.fetchImage(`labeled_images/${label}/${i}.jpg`)
```